# Insert Specific Data from Worksheet Using VLookup

Tags: vba, excel

Could someone help me please - I've got one worksheet, and on an entry of a code I need it to pull through certain set cells from that row and display them on the active sheet.
This is as far as I've got and might give some idea of how ignorant I am in the way of VBA, and it doesn't work.

```
Sub AddProduct()
On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
Dim Code As Long
Code = B4
Sheets("Code Input Sheet").Range(A9) = Application.VLookup(Code,Worksheets("Cost Sheet").Range("A2:XFD1048576"), 1, False)
ActiveCell.End(xlRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection = Application.VLookup(Code, Worksheets("Cost Sheet").Range("A2:XFD1048576"), 2, False)
ActiveCell.End(xlRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection = Application.VLookup(Code, Worksheets("Cost Sheet").Range("A2:XFD1048576"), 5, False)
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
MsgBox "Code doesn't exist."
End If
End Sub
```

Hopefully this makes sense
Thanks

---

### EDIT

[image: Screenshot]

I probably need to start from scratch, but here's basically what I need: The user to enter a code in B4, runs the macro through the button which looks up on the second Sheet if it exists, and pulls through three cells from that code's row to A9:C9 on the first sheet. Then hopefully the process can be repeated with the data going to the next row below. Hopefully this isn't too much of an ask!

Comment: Can you explain a little more? What's not working? Do you get an error? Or does the sub run, just nothing happens?  Do you have a sample table of "before and after" that you can show us?

Comment: Sorry - probably didn't explain properly. For some reason it's going straight to the ErrorHandler now, but before it ran the sub but did nothing. Have edited original post. Thanks.

Comment: Take the error handler out, then see what line throws an error, and what that error is. ...and you have `Code` as a `long`, but set it to `B4`? Do you mean `Code = Range("B4")`?

Comment: Took it out, the `Sheets("Code Input Sheet").Range(A9) = Application.VLookup(Code,Worksheets("Cost Sheet").Range("A2:XFD1048576"), 1, False)` line throws it back. I don't think I do mean `Code = Range ("B4")` ... little bit ignorant sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the VLOOKUP use the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx):

```
Sub AddProduct()
Dim code As Variant
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet

code = ws.Range("B4")

'Find code and set c to the cell    
Set c = Worksheets("Cost Sheet").Range("A:A").Find(code)

If c is Nothing Then
    'if the code is not found
    MsgBox "Not Found"
    Exit Sub
Else
    'this finds the next empty row
    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lastrow) = c
    ws.Range("B" & lastrow) = c.Offset(, 1)
    ws.Range("C" & lastrow) = c.Offset(, 4)
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a compile error for  `If c = Nothing Then` on `Nothing` as an invalide use of object. Also, how do I then select the correct cells from the "Cost Sheet" and add them below at A9:C9?

Comment: @JG2703 see edit it should be fixed.  The `.offfset` is similar to the third criteria in the vlookup.  it states that you want the cell 1 space to the right.

Comment: It comes up with the error message "Type Mismatch"?

Comment: It doesn't actually come up with the VBA and show it - just displays the box, no highlighting of the error as per usual..??

Comment: When the error box comes up hit debug and a line should be highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Sorry, yes wouldn't do it first time but now I have. The line is `code = ws.Range("B4")`

Comment: @JG2703 Then code is not a number. Change it to a variant and it will work.  See edit

Comment: Thanks so much! Stupid - I should have pointed that out. Many thanks